# airflow initdb: ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLString'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLString'` on running `airflow initdb`

```
File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 71, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 27, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder.baseviews import BaseView
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .forms import GeneralModelConverter
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .fieldwidgets import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/fieldwidgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wtforms.widgets import html_params, HTMLString
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLString'
```

- apache-airflow ==  1.10.9, SQLAlchemy == 1.3.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recent release](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0) of WTForms broke Airflow. You have 2 options:

1) Install it with constraints

For **Python 3.7**

```sh
pip install apache-airflow==1.10.9 \
   --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt
```

For **Python 3.6**

```sh
pip install apache-airflow==1.10.9 \
   --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.6.txt
```

2) Pin WTForms

```sh
pip install wtforms==2.3.1
```

Comment: The constraint urls are not valid anymore. Use those:
Python3.6: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.9/constraints-3.6.txt
Python3.7: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.9/constraints-3.7.txt

Answer (score 1):

It's related to latest wtforms release, you can see the details in https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8506.

Run the

```
pip install wtforms<2.3.0
```

before installing airflow, so this dependency is met by airflow and the upgraded package is not installed.