# Apache Airflow initdb not working on AWS EC2

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to setup apache airflow on aws ec2(ubuntu 18.04)

Python version: 3.6.9
Pip Version: 9.0.1

To Install Apache Airflow I have used below command.

`pip3 install apache-airflow[postgres,celery,rabbitmq,ldap,crypto,aws]`

while I execute `airflow initdb` it shows me error

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 71, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder.baseviews import BaseView
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .forms import GeneralModelConverter
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .fieldwidgets import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/fieldwidgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wtforms.widgets import html_params, HTMLString
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLString'
```

can somebody help me with this?

Comment: same steps were working fine earlier but now it is showing this error.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362750/airflow-initdb-importerror-cannot-import-name-htmlstring

Comment: @Mariusz I just tried the fresh installation on a new AWS instance but got the same error again.

Comment: Steps:  1.  pip3 install "wtforms<2.3.0"   2. pip3 install apache-airflow[postgres,celery,rabbitmq,ldap,crypto,aws]  3.  airflow initdb

Comment: I tried adding --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt after pip install and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Mariusz for the help.

I followed the steps mentioned
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8506#issuecomment-617515743

and add --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt after my pip install command and it got working.

It was an error with WTForms new release version